# stopping setup.py from installing as egg

Tags: python, pydev, setuptools, easy-install

How do I stop `setup.py` from installing a package as an egg?  Or even better, how do I `easy_install` from installing a package as an `egg`?

> sudo python setup.py install

The reason being that `PyDev` is rather picky about packages in `egg` format...  The package I am interested in at the moment is `boto`.

**Update:** I found the *brute force* way of doing it:

```
sudo easy_install -m boto
cd path/to/boto-xyz.egg
sudo mv boto ..
sudo rm -rf boto-xyz.egg
```

Answer (score 87):

### Solution 1:

I feel like I'm missing something subtle or important (encountering this page years after the question was asked and not finding a satisfying answer) however the following works fine for me:

```
python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --root=/
```

Compressed `*.egg` files are an invention of [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) (I'm not a big fan of them although I understand why they were created) and because the `setup.py` script is using (and may require) setuptools, the package ends up being installed as a compressed `*.egg` file.

### Solution 2:

The command line options above are [similar to those](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/e0522c4/pip/req/req_install.py#L832) used by pip (the Python package manager) which hints at another way to stop a package from being installed as a compressed `*.egg` file: Just use pip! If you have a directory containing a `setup.py` script you can run the following command in that directory to install the package using pip:

```
pip install .
```

This is an improvement over the `setup.py` command above because it tracks additional metadata (e.g. tracking of installed files allows for more reliable removal).

Comment: Ha! I've been using pip for years and didn't know `pip install .` was possible. :-)

Comment: This is especially important to know for people who download and do source installs the old way with `python setup.py install` which often makes an `egg` install.

Comment: `pip install .` works on Windows 10 as well and fixed my issue of downloading a repo from github and having it go into a `.egg` when installing in a `virtualenv`

Comment: I am so sick of `setuptools.setup`... everything simply works again after switching back to `disutils.core.setup`. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 19):

Years later, same problem, not satisfied with the accepted answer. Found this in Google groups:

```
pushd /path/to/my/package/ 
python setup.py sdist 
popd 
pip install /path/to/my/package/dist/package-1.0.tar.gz
```

Explanation:
`python setup.py sdist` creates a *source distribution* which naturally is not an *.egg! The resulting archive (.tar.gz in unix, .zip in windows) can be installed like any remote module with pip. It doesn't even require additional parameters! This results in the desired fully browsable module.

Comment: What benefit is there of using `pusd popd` vs `cd  cd -`? Or is it just taste?

Comment: I was just referencing. I'd say it's just taste (flavor: Linux).

Comment: This does not address packages that contain compiled binary code.  I don't think it really fully addresses the issue here.