# .egg dirs in site-packages when installing python packages?

Tags: python, django, installation, package

So I decided to install python packages (technically **Django apps**) directly from the downloaded tar file, by extracting it and using the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```

However, inside my `site-packages` directory, I find that the package was installed inside a `.egg` directory that also has version numbers. The directories look annoyingly like this:

```
site-packages/django_cms-2.1.3-py2.7.egg/cms
site-packages/django_cms-2.1.3-py2.7.egg/mptt
```

I need the packages to install as a directory with the package name with no `.egg` or version number, otherwise, Django can't find the package. It should be like this:

```
site-packages/cms
site-packages/mptt
```

Attempting to install the same package from `pip`, and it works fine. This is frustrating, so some help would be appreciated.

I tracked down a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301003/stopping-setup-py-from-installing-as-egg) that discusses something similar, but it didn't give a solution that worked.

The Django project is unable to locate the packages I installed because the packages aren't installed at the root of `site-packages` dir. Instead, it resides inside the `.egg` directories. What I had to do is manually move the package to the root, but how do you correctly install python packages?

Also, I didn't suppress the `easy-install.pth` file, but it isn't picked up by `PyDev`.

Comment: You haven't explained what didn't work how.

Comment: Exactly. It doesn't matter what the folder is named. If I had to guess, you're probably talking about not being able to load templates, in which case you just need to add the egg loader to your template loaders list.

Comment: A package doesn't need to be in `site-packages/` if there's a `.pth` file that points to it. Did you suppress generation of the `.pth` file?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that was the problem until you pointed out the .pth file as I realized that it was occasionally running fine in a shell. However, I noticed that not all of the packages actually install itself into the .pth file either. Now is there a solution to this beyond just manually moving the package within the virtualenv?

Comment: And now virtualenv is in the mix. This stuff is important...