# How to write setup.py for installing python module without making .egg file

Tags: python-2.7, setuptools, distutils, setup.py, egg

I want to create a `setup.py` file, which will install a Python module (say, `abc`) and make a folder `abc` inside of `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` instead of making an `abc.egg` file.

Comment: inside my setup.py, i tried zip_safe= False, but still my packages are getting installed as zip folder instead of directory.

Comment: I want to install my package as a directory, not as an egg folder

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33791008/3437454), you can use

`pip install .`

to install the package from inside the `/path/to/your/setup.py/` to achieve that result.