# Python module by SWIG in conda: Where do I have to place which file?

Tags: python, windows, conda, swig

I am trying to generate Python bindings for a C++ shared library with SWIG and distribute the project with conda. The build process seems to work as I can execute

```py
import mymodule as m
ret = m.myfunctioninmymodule()
```

in my build directory. Now I want to install files that are created (namely, `mymodule.py` and `_mymodule.pyd`) in my conda environment on Windows so that I can access them from everywhere. But where do I have to place the files?

**What I have tried so far** is to put both files in a package together with a `__init__.py` (which is empty, however) and write a setup.py as suggested [here](https://thomastrapp.com/blog/building-a-pypi-package-for-a-modern-cpp-project/). The package has the form

```
- mypackage
 |- __init__.py
 |- mymodule.py
 |- _mymodule.pyd
```

and is installed under `C:\mypathtoconda\conda\envs\myenvironmentname\Lib\site-packages\mypackage-1.0-py3.6-win-amd64.egg`. However, the python import (see above) fails with

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_mymodule'
```

It should be noted that under Linux this approach with the package works perfectly fine.

**Edit:** The `__init__.py` is empty because this is sufficient to build a package. I am not sure, however, what belongs in there. Do I have to give a path to certain components?

Comment: Apparently, the package was installed as zip archive under Windows (in extracted form under Linux, though). Using pip install . instead of calling setup.py directly lead to success (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33791008/9450461)).