# Installing Python package WITHOUT pip install or conda install

Tags: pip, directory, command, conda, pyinstaller

I am trying to install pyinstaller on my device, but due to security protocols for my projects I cannot use pip or conda install in any form. I also do not have sudo.

How do I manually manipulate my files to install pyinstaller or run the setup.py file without also needing to use pip?

*The overall problem is that I want to compile an app I've made with PyQt5 with access to a database all on a network folder, and hoping that compiling it will help run it faster from the network folder so there isn't communication back and forth between the network folder and the user's python installation.*

```
python setup.py install

running bdist_egg
Error: Aborting implicit building of eggs. To install from source, use `pip install .` instead of `python setup.py install`.
```

```
python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --root=\
```

Writes to /Apps\Anaconda\Scripts which starts with a network line. Which makes it look like it succeeded but the package is not at /Apps/Anaconda/Scripts, so it did not succeed.

Everything on this link: [Stopping setup.py from installing as egg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301003/stopping-setup-py-from-installing-as-egg)

**Edit:

```
python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --root=C:\
```

Has worked, unfortunately it required (for pyinstaller) that I perform the command for all missing dependencies, but it works!**

Comment: Without going into details installing a wheel is "just" unzipping it into the right locations. So one can get something that works well enough by "just" unzipping a wheel somewhere on disk and adding this "somwhere" to `sys.path` (maybe via the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable for example). And I guess multiple wheels can be unzipped to the same location. -- Also unzipping a wheel can be done with Python itself: [*`python -m zipfile --extract pyinstaller.whl path/to/target/directory`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#cmdoption-zipfile-extract)

Answer (score 1):

```
python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --root=C:\
```

Running this command for every necessary dependency has allowed me to use pyinstaller.